# Uncertain about file-locking mechanism in C#.NET

Tags: c#, file-locking

In my test-environment I have two physical Windows 7 clients. Both have access to a network share, hosted on a Windows Server system.

The clients, respectively, run an application which may attempt to operate (read or write) on the same text file at the same time.

I want to use the [FileInfo.Open()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3wke8tz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to realize different scenarios:

**Scenario 1:** The application allows reading at the same time. It should fail if another instance is actually writing to it.

I would use

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
using (FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
{
    // Do some read operations...
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close file-stream...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

for that.

**Scenario 2:** Only one instance is allowed to open a file when attempt to write to it. And it should fail if any other instance is actually reading it.

I would use

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filePath);
using (FileStream fs = fi.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
{
    // Do some write operations...
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to close file-stream...");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

for that.

---

With the code-snippets above my scenarios work as expected. Even though I closed one instance when inside the `using(...)` statement, the file gets "unlocked".

**Q1:** I think about if there could anything happen on an application crash, so that other instances access to the file will be denied (for a couple of time?).

**Q2:** What happens on loosing network connection while a file is opened?

**Q3:** Are there any reasons to (additionally) use the [FileStream.Lock()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock) and [Unlock()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.unlock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods to explicitly lock und unlock a file?

**Q4:** Does the servers' system require anything to make that way of file-locking running?

**Q5:** Are there additional points I have to think about?

Comment: Consider what will happen if someone tries to open/modify the file with a program that is not within your control. They will not always be using the lock types you are expecting.

Comment: @CathalMF Good point. But I think, in my case, this is up to the end-users to not to do so. The people will (hopefully) know what they are doing :-)

Comment: We all hope our users know what they're doing. But there is always that one person!! Just make sure your app doesnt explode if someone opens the file with some combination of the share privleges and reading/writing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... could anything happen on an application crash

Not particularly, the lock is instantly released when the OS cleans up the shrapnel and closes any files that were not closed by the app.

> What happens on loosing network connection while a file is opened?

You'll get a runtime exception, IOException.  Only recoverable by restoring the network connection and re-opening the file.  Networks are generally reliable enough to consider not doing this automatically, YMMV.

> Are there any reasons to (additionally) use the FileStream.Lock() ...

No. These function lock file *data* instead of file access.  The kind of thing a database engine would do.  It never applies to a text file since they are streams and you never know the exact file position of a line of text in the file.

> Does the servers' system require anything ...

No, this is built into the operating system.

> Are there additional points I have to think about?

You probably ought to think more about writing the file, somebody is going to have to do it.  Using FileShare.None is simple but tends to be a bit crude on text files, particularly if they are log files that are always kept open.  It is technically possible for an app to read a file that's being written.  Tends to turn out well since text files are only ever appended to.  You'd use FileShare.Read in the app that writes the file and FileShare.ReadWrite in the app that reads the file.  Not a typo.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Can you explain me, or share a link, why System B knows that System A is actually processing a file on a network share?

Comment: System B doesn't know, it asks whatever system owns the file.  Job of the network redirector.  I don't know of any links.

Comment: Additionally, which may be answered in my previous question, how does the file recognize that it is not locked any more, if the locking system instantly crashes(shut-down)?

Comment: A file doesn't know anything, the operating system does.  It keeps track of opened files through their handle and arbitrates access to the underlying file object.  Closing a file tells the OS to stop keeping track.

Answer (score 2):

The File locking you're referring to is done at the OS level. So if you're application crashes, errors out and so on, it'll release the file. That applies to Q1 and Q2 (although Q2 depends on network topology and backing storage). Beware locking a file can cause weird performance issues with a backing storage that has buffering enabled.
Q3, the Lock, Unlock refered to there is not a file lock, but bytes within a file. That's a completely different concept and it WILL cause you weird behavior on NAS type storage
Q4, like I said before it's a OS level concept.
Q5. Think of a better way of managing this, using a file is a relatively old concept however, sharing a file among multiple computer on a network, IMHO, is asking for weird head-scratching behavior. Modern file storage is not geared towards this concept and with buffering, latency and security it becomes challenging. Avoid it where you can. Failing that, make sure you optimize your application so it opens the file, writes, close and flushes the stream as quickly as possible.